# php code for button counter

Tags: php, counter

Am trying to run a php code which counts button clicks. It increments to 1 and then it doesn't count. here is my code:

```
<?php
if ($_SERVER["REQUEST_METHOD"] == "POST") {
  $counter = isset($_POST['counter']) ? $_POST['counter'] : 0;
  if(isset($_POST["button"])){
    $counter++;
    echo $counter;
   }
}
?>
<form action = "<?php echo htmlspecialchars($_SERVER["PHP_SELF"]);?>" method = post>
  <input type = "submit" name = "button" value = "vote" >
</form>
```

Am not a php expert so can anybody please tell me where am going wrong?

Thanks

Comment: You will need to count your button click with js not PHP. Unless you store the php value in a txt file or DB.

Comment: You're not including the `$_POST['counter']` value in your form.

Comment: Or at least you should use $_SESSION to store the count for the single user

Comment: @Mr.Concolato, is it the problem that am not storing it anywhere?

Answer (score 0):

Use this php:

```
<?php
if(isset($_POST["button"])){
    $counter++;
    echo counter;
}
?>
```

Also, use this for the opening `<form>` element

```
<form method="post" action="<?php echo htmlspecialchars($_SERVER["PHP_SELF"]);?>">
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
<?php
if ($_SERVER["REQUEST_METHOD"] == "POST") {
  $counter = isset($_POST['counter']) ? $_POST['counter'] : 0;
  if(isset($_POST["button"])){
    $counter++;
    echo $counter;
   }
}
?>
<form action = "<?php echo $_SERVER["PHP_SELF"]; ?>" method = post>
  <input type = "hidden" name = "counter" value = "<?php echo $counter; ?>" />
  <input type = "submit" name = "button" value = "vote" />
</form>
```

Answer (score 0):

Store the count in a session.  Note that this stores a separate count for each user.  If you want one single count that is shared between all users then you'll need to store it in a database.

```
<?php
// Start the session
session_start();
// Make sure a session variable exists
if ( !isset($_SESSION['count']) ) {
    $_SESSION['count'] = 0;
}
// Check to see if a vote has been submitted
$vote = isset($_POST['button']) ? $_POST['button'] : false;
if ( $vote ) {
    // Increment the vote
    $_SESSION['count']++;
}
?>
<form action="<?php echo $_SERVER["PHP_SELF"] ?>" method="post">
    <input type="submit" name="button" value="Vote">
</form>
```